# Django: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__create_post.author_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__create_post.author_id

models:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more information, when is the error occurring? What line of code causes the error?

Comment: Your author `default=None` which in your database is `NULL`. Remove the default kwarg and make sure you set an author every time you create a Post. or add the kwarg `null=True` to the Post author field

Comment: i tried null=True and it gives the same error.

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and the `python manage.py migrate` after making the change?

Comment: yes but it still gives the same error

Comment: its when i migrate that it gives the error

Comment: Sounds like you could have a broken migration then, likely due to your database already containing posts with `NULL` author fields or no author field in the database before the migration has been made. Try deleting your database or (renaming it to keep a backup) and run migrations again

Comment: i think deleting the databased worked thank you

Comment: If you are only working locally and you don't have a production version of the site, I recommend deleting your migration files in `yourapp/migrations/`and recreateting them with `makemigrations`. This will prevent errors in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this `default=None` because your field don't accept null values by default try to make field like this :

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

it should work ... but you need to delete last migrations file like the pic [image]